# Наследование нескольких форм от базовой

Tags: asp.net, c#, asp.net-webforms, asp.net-mvc

Всем привет. Немного предыстории.

Чтобы лучше понять, что я имею в виду, приведу куски кода. Код получился объемный, но простой, поэтому не поленитесь, господа, с ним ознакомится.

Ситуация следующая. Есть несколько WebForm (страницы aspx). Код их представлен ниже:

**Страница 1:**

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
   <title>Страница 1</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div>
         <asp:Label runat="server" ID="myLabelPage_1"></asp:Label>
     </div>
   </form>
  </body>
 </html>

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm_1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
         // Общие для обеих страниц поля.
         public string FirstName;
         public string LastName;

         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
              myLabelPage_1.Text = "Страница 1 " + FirstName + " " + LastName;
         }
     }
 }
```

**Страница 2:**

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
   <title>Страница 2</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div>
         <asp:Label runat="server" ID="myLabelPage_2"></asp:Label>
     </div>
   </form>
  </body>
 </html>

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm_2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
         // Общие для обеих страниц поля.
         public string FirstName;
         public string LastName;

         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
              myLabelPage_2.Text = "Страница 2 " + FirstName + " " + LastName;
         }
     }
 }
```

Как можно заметить, что в классе `WebForm_1`, что `WebForm_2` присутствуют одинаковые поля, это:

```
 public string FirstName;
 public string LastName;
```

Следовательно, напрашивается мысль, чтобы вынести их в отдельный базовый класс, который будет наследоваться от `System.Web.UI.Page` и содержать данные поля, что в принципе я и делаю. Для этого создаю класс MyBasePage.

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
     // Базовый класс для наших страниц.
     public partial class MyBasePage : System.Web.UI.Page
     {
          public string FirstName;
          public string LastName;
     }
}
```

Далее я классы `WebForm_1` и `WebForm_2`, вместо наследования от системного `System.Web.UI.Page`, наследую от моего класса `MyBasePage`.

**Страница 1**

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm_1 : MyBasePage
    {
         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
               FirstName = "Вася";
               LastName = "Иванов";

               myLabelPage_1.Text = "Страница 2 " + FirstName + " " + LastName;
         }
     }
 }
```

**Страница 2**

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm_2 : MyBasePage
    {
         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
               FirstName = "Петя";
               LastName = "Петров";

               myLabelPage_2.Text = "Страница 2 " + FirstName + " " + LastName;
         }
     }
 }
```

В результате по наследству я получаю поля:

```
 public string FirstName;
 public string LastName;
```

**Теперь сам вопрос.**

Обзательно ли при создании **пользовательского класса**, который **будет являться базовым** классом для страниц ASPX, создавать **полноценную форму**, которая содержит и **разметку ASPX**, и **code behind**, и наследоваться от нее?

Или можно поступить, как сделано у меня, т.е.:

- Просто создать класс C#, унаследовать его от `System.Web.UI.Page`.
- Наследовать от созданного пользовательского класса вновь создаваемые страницы ASPX.

Насколько так делать правильно, так сказать, по феншую, и не противоречит ли это каким-нибудь соглашениям, принятым при разработке на ASP.NET WebForms?

Почему задаю такой вопрос? Просто в Интернете много видел примеров, когда **базовый класс** для WebForm создается на основе другой веб-формы, которая **уже содержит** и **code behind** и **разметку ASPX**. В моем же случае разметки **ASPX нет**, есть **только код на C#**.

Answer (score 1):

По идее, не обязательно. Главное, чтобы дизайнеры не падали :)